# Ionic firebase, user profile in sidemenu saves using Events class but is gone as soon as I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

good day. I am trying to put my user's information in the sidemenu, my research lead me to use the Events class. My data in subscribe saves, but as soon as I refresh the page or close the application it is destroyed. How do I get data again. All imports are working, the problem is saving the data after the application closes or if I refresh it in the browser

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any;
  profileName: string;
  profileEmail: string;
  user: any;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public events: Events, public platform: Platform,
   public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    if(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')==='1')
    {
      this.events.subscribe('user', (user)=>{
        this.profileName = user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname,
        this.profileEmail = user.email
        console.log(user);
      });
      this.pages = [
        { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
        { title: 'Messages', component: ChatlistPage }
      ];
      this.rootPage = HomePage; //HomePage
    }
    else{
      this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    }
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  logoutUser() {
    localStorage.clear();
    window.localStorage.clear();
    this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean to say the data that's stored in localstorage is cleared/destroyed? after you refresh or close the application?

Comment: nope. I need a data to be in application level hence the use of Events but when I refresh the page that data is lost. How do I solve this? Any ideas?

Comment: huh, so you are expecting the published event data to be available after the the app is refreshed or closed and reopened or refreshed in the browser? Well i referred the API and i do not see it's saving the state of that event data anywhere in storage. And which is also a correct behavior and that's how a pub/sub must be. If you have to specifically use the published data, you must save it's state either in storage or to any database for future use. i.e, the queue which holds the data temporarily is being cleared after channels that subscribed to the event receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, so you are expecting the published event data to be available after the the app is refreshed or closed and reopened or refreshed in the browser? Well i referred the API and i do not see it's saving the state of that event data anywhere in storage. And which is also a correct behavior and that's how a pub/sub must be. If you have to specifically use the published data, you must save it's state either in storage or to any database for future use. i.e, the queue which holds the data temporarily is being cleared after channels that subscribed to the event receive the data.

I do not see the code where you publish it? More importantly separate the components so that you would know which one is publishing and which one is subscribed to that topic. It's always easier to debug problems that way.

Read [here](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/the-publish-subscribe-pattern-on-rails) about pub/sub to understand it better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to architect your app this way. `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)...` should deliver user state.